# socket.io client using Go

Tags: go, websocket, socket.io

Starting with a working `socket.io` example (back-end: Python/Flask, front-end: socket.io.js v2.0.3), I now try to set up a client with Go but can't even pass the handshake phase. Apologies for the long post... (At the end I have also added a Python client which does what I want to implement in Go)

#### (The following work):

---

**back-end:**

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/endpoint')
def connect():
    print("Client connected with request sid "+request.sid)

@socketio.on('join', namespace='/endpoint')
def join(message):
    print("Server received from client:" +message)
    print("Client just joined room with request sid "+request.sid)
    join_room(request.sid)
```

**front-end:**

```
namespace = '/endpoint';
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);

var client_join_message = "This is a client";    
socket.emit('join', client_join_message);
```

**Developer tools:** I notice a few requests until the browser and the server select to use websockets and exchange frames:

```
http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LxcgetJ
http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgetf&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3
http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgeti&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3
ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3
http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgetw&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3
http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgetx&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3
```

**Server logs:**

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LxcgetJ HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.000322
Client connected with request sid 025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3
"POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgetf&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.000806
(6450) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 45034)
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgeti&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3 HTTP/1.1" 200 227 0.003941
"POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgetw&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.001650
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lxcgetx&sid=025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3 HTTP/1.1" 200 215 0.000235
Server received from client:This is a client
Client just joined room with request sid 025e105a5093467d994a891367380aa3
```

#### My try with Go, (doesn't work):

---

The code comes from this [client](https://github.com/graarh/golang-socketio/blob/master/examples/client.go) example in [github.com/graarh/golang-socketio](https://github.com/graarh/golang-socketio):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/graarh/golang-socketio"
    "github.com/graarh/golang-socketio/transport"
    "log"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    c, err := gosocketio.Dial(
        gosocketio.GetUrl("127.0.0.1", 5000, false),
        transport.GetDefaultWebsocketTransport())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = c.On(gosocketio.OnDisconnection, func(h *gosocketio.Channel) {
        log.Fatal("Disconnected")
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = c.On(gosocketio.OnConnection, func(h *gosocketio.Channel) {
        log.Println("Connected")
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

**Go code output:**

```
Connected
```

**Server logs:**

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 200 0 1.004291
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? With the Go code I don't see any `sid`, `transport=polling`... Also, there are only a few questions tagged with `[go] [socket.io]`, which makes me think I've chosen the wrong path... I would be grateful for any thoughts, ideas on this.

---

#### @John Weldon

Your code produces the following:

Client:

```
$ go run gotest5.go 
2017/10/11 11:21:40 Connected
2017/10/11 11:21:40 result ""
2017/10/11 11:21:40 Done
```

Server:

```
(4380) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(4380) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 38860)
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2017 11:21:40] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 200 0 0.003100
```

Notice that the server functions `on.('connect'...)` and `on.('join',...)` didn't produce logs.

---

#### Python client (it works):

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace

class ThisNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        print('[Connected]')
    def on_reconnect(self):
        print('[Reconnected]')
    def on_disconnect(self):
        print('[Disconnected]')

with SocketIO('127.0.0.1', 5000, ThisNamespace) as socketIO:
    this_namespace = socketIO.define(ThisNamespace, '/endpoint')
```

client logs:

```
python3 test.py 
[Connected]
[Disconnected]
[Disconnected]
```

server logs:

```
(6047) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(6047) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 38900)
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2017 11:53:27] "GET /socket.io/?t=1507712007314-0&transport=polling&EIO=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.000859
(6047) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 38902)
Client connected with request sid 919ed69264dd4e9f93e7af0294970dbd
Client disconnected with request.sid 919ed69264dd4e9f93e7af0294970dbd
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2017 11:53:27] "GET /socket.io/?sid=919ed69264dd4e9f93e7af0294970dbd&transport=websocket&EIO=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 0.032171
```

Comment: The `Dial` function is used to connect to a server as a client, but you're trying to create a server. You need to use `NewServer`, which is shown in the library's documentation.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I want to connect to a server, not create a new one. So the use of `Dial()` is correct here, isn' t it?

Comment: My apologies, I misread and thought you were trying to move the backend to Go. I notice with your current setup, the requests via http are logged and have `transport=polling`, and the request via ws is logged as a client connecting and `transport=websocket`. However, when you are using the Go client, you log an *http* request with `transport=websocket`.

Comment: Yes you are right. By digging more to the source code of [golang-socketio](https://github.com/graarh/golang-socketio) I don't see any option to do the same thing javascript does in the browser. Also this handshake / polling phase is not very well documented: [Document the handshake process #10](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol/issues/10)

Comment: In fact yor JS and Go clients work different ways. JS uses polling and Go tries to use websockets. Could you restrict available transport to websocket only? Like this: `io.connect("http://your.domain.com", {transports: ['websocket']});`

Comment: Have you tried to connect with pure browser WebSockes?

Comment: I have noticed that long polling is for the first steps and then `ws` are used. For the back end that I have now, I cannot bypass this step because during this phase an `sid` is also exchanged.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It connects, yes and then you don't do anything with that connection (aka call join), so you won't see subsequent calls...

Comment: started to comment... by ran out of characters )

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing it right except you forgot to actually send the `join` message, maybe something like:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "runtime"
        "sync"
        "time"

        "github.com/graarh/golang-socketio"
        "github.com/graarh/golang-socketio/transport"
)

func doSomethingWith(c *gosocketio.Client, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        if res, err := c.Ack("join", "This is a client", time.Second*3); err != nil {
                log.Printf("error: %v", err)
        } else {
                log.Printf("result %q", res)
        }
        wg.Done()
}

func main() {

        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

        c, err := gosocketio.Dial(
                gosocketio.GetUrl("127.0.0.1", 3003, false),
                transport.GetDefaultWebsocketTransport())
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        err = c.On(gosocketio.OnDisconnection, func(h *gosocketio.Channel) {
                log.Fatal("Disconnected")
        })
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        err = c.On(gosocketio.OnConnection, func(h *gosocketio.Channel) {
                log.Println("Connected")
        })
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(1)
        go doSomethingWith(c, wg)
        wg.Wait()
        log.Printf("Done")
}
```

Notice the goroutine call to the function that actually communicates the 'join' message to the server.

Also, notice the use of a `sync.WaitGroup` to block until the goroutine completes, instead of using `time.Sleep()` to wait.

Comment: Thanks John. This is the example I've been using too. For some reason the 2 server functions `socketio.on('connect'...)` and `socketio.on('join'...)` are never executed. I really think that this library tries to directly connect to a `ws` and does not implement the initial steps that `socket.io` requires as a protocol.

Comment: Well, the two main differences are 1) you're only waiting for 1 second instead of 60 seconds, and 2) you're not actually doing any `Join` calls - the example issues several `Join` requests in goroutines before waiting 60 seconds for the goroutines to complete.

Comment: @tgogos - I've updated my answer with an example that should give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort John. I've included the results of your code in my question.

Comment: I've also added the results from python client

Answer (score 1):

According to commentws above, we've found websocket connection itself is working. I think problem is here - `socket.io` was developed many years ago when native WebSockets were not well supported by majority of browsers and inermediate servers/proxies/routers. So it has a special checks and fallbacks when to upgrade and downgrade a connection (to longpolling for example). If you have already installed connection you may start working without special key exchanges with another protocol.

Try to start using connection and performing next steps at application level logics (`Join` and so on). Is it working?

I think nowadays WS are supported well for 99% of clients. If you want not to loose chance some client will be not working you may keep `sockets.io` in project. But sometimes you'll have to realize its connections logics in WS.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Eugene, more or less I've come to the same conclusions while searching for this...