# Connect to a websocket - setup by socket.io - without socket.io

Tags: go, websocket, socket.io, gorilla

I'm trying to connect to `wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com` from [cryptocompare.com](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api#-api-web-socket-), using the go gorilla lib.

Is it just me, or isn't this possible? They're using socket.io as their backend.

Comment: Socket.io adds a layer over the websocket protocol. You need to implement that layer, possibly using an existing socket.io package.

Comment: Hmm, no other way?

Comment: You must have code that implements the protocol used by the endpoint.

Comment: Well, will look through the source. Also, do you know if I can connect to a server from `go-socket.io`?

Comment: I was looking for something similar some months ago and didn't find any Go library that would fit my needs. You can check my question here: [socket.io client using Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561747/socket-io-client-using-go)